# How to add accent in text to speech in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I want to read a text with accent but haven't get success .I have searched more and have fine out that we can change speech language but not accent .Is this possible in android or not if possible then please suggest me how to do this.
Thanks
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible yet. You can at most store voice for certain words. Look at the possibility of a custom TTS engine, if that is feasible.

Comment: Actually storing voice and just playing it is not a good practice.

Comment: @Sunny:only for some words in which you want an accent. It is obviously not feasible for longer sentences. There is no alternative yet.

Comment: But how is it feasible for some words

Comment: In pro Android 3 the authors say "To get the
same voice as everything else, we want to use the TTS engine to make the sound and
record the result, and then we tell the TTS engine to use our recorded sound in place of
what it would normally do. The trick is to provide text that sounds like what we want." It would be best if refer Using Audio Files for Your Voice section in Exploring Text to Speech chapter from the book

Comment: Thanks Akhil, Actually my requirement was something other but thanks you so much for giving me this great idea..

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Not Possible in Android. Sorry If I am wrong.